# When $\ell^2$-convergence implies $\ell^1$- convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\ell^1$ (sequences taking their values in $\mathbb R$), where $x_n=(x_{i,n})_{i\in\mathbb N}$.

What are sufficient conditions on the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_n\|_{\ell^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{i,n}^2=0
$$
implies that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_n\|_{\ell^1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_{i,n}|=0\qquad ?
$$
I am trying to prove that a sufficient condition is
$$
\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\| x_n\|_{\ell^1}<+\infty,
$$
but is it true ?

EDIT : Ok, it's clearly not the case. Any other idea for a sufficient condition which actually works  ?

Comment: Your condition won't work. Consider $x_n={1\over n}(e_1+\cdots +e_n)$. $x_n$ has $\ell_1$-norm of $1$ and $\ell_2$-norm of $1/\sqrt n$.

Comment: You're right ...

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything useful, except for putting restrictions on  the cardinality of the support of the $x_n$ and using the (tight) inequality $\Vert x\Vert_{\ell_1}\le \sqrt n\Vert x\Vert_{\ell_2}$ for $x\in\Bbb R^n$.